# Trouble making an image heat map multiple answer

Tags: heatmap

I'm trying to select on an image different sections, per each section I need to get the coordinates (I've got as far as geting a single response coordinate saved and I'm happy!) thing is when doing multiple circles I'm lost on 3 things.

First I need my bad implemented loop to cicle thorugh my boxes I just can't seem to find why "i" doesn't change on click...

Second a button that gets my loop back to 0 and erases the circles on the canvas

Third no more than 5 circles can be placed...

I've got to a point where my question is too specific to research I think? :( and I'm just starting with javascript here... please do help me,

Here is my fiddle thanks for all your help, and if this works for you go for it I left the single answer response there commented =3

http://plnkr.co/edit/ja9fNtOyd8lzH6BekDpo?p=preview

```
<div id="Click">Seleccione las áreas de la imagen que más le gustan </div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<img src="http://i332.photobucket.com/albums/m340/carlospatino21/megaman-5.jpg" alt="" border="0" id="mmc">
<style>
    #myCanvas
    {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 30px;
    background-color: transparent;
    opacity:0.5;
    border-style: dotted;;
    max-width:295px;
    max-height:337px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    display: block;


    }

    #mmc
    {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 30px;
    z-index: 0;
    display: block;
    max-width:295px;
    max-height:337px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;

    }
    #Click
    {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1;

    }

</style>




    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="295px" height="337px" onclick="evt2()" ></canvas>


    <script>
    function writeMessage(canvas, message) {
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            context.font = '15pt Calibri';
            context.fillStyle = 'black';
            context.fillText(message, 10, 25);}

 function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
        var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        return {
          x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
          y: evt.clientY - rect.top
        };
      }
      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

      canvas.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
        var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
        var message = 'Mouse position: ' + mousePos.x + ',' + mousePos.y;


  var centerX = event.clientX ;
  var centerY = event.clientY - 30 ;

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(centerX, centerY,20,0, 2 * Math.PI);
  context.fillStyle = 'green';
  context.fill();
  context.lineWidth = 1;
  context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
  context.stroke();

      }, false);

//function evt2(){  
//document.getElementById("canvas1_NewVar1").value = event.clientX + ',' + (event.clientY-30);} 

 var d = "canvas1_NewVar";


 for ( var i = 1; i < 5; i++ ) 
  onclick = (function(){return function evt2() {
document.getElementById( d+i).value = event.clientX + ',' + (event.clientY-30)
};})(i);





    </script>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<input  id="canvas1_NewVar1" type="text" size="20" class="puntos" onclick="evt2()" >
<input  id="canvas1_NewVar2" type="text" size="20" class="puntos" onclick="evt2()" >
<input  id="canvas1_NewVar3" type="text" size="20" class="puntos" onclick="evt2()" >
<input  id="canvas1_NewVar4" type="text" size="20" class="puntos" onclick="evt2()" >
<input  id="canvas1_NewVar5" type="text" size="20" class="puntos" onclick="evt2()" >
```

Comment: Your `onclick` event shouldn't be inside your for loop. Have a single `onclick` event and keep track of the value of `i` (increment it every click or however you want to handle it) to set the corresponding inputs value

Comment: Ahm... I think it's not inside of the for... but maybe I'm not understanding you.... I'm sorry...

Comment: I can't edit...
LINE 1 for ( var i = 1; i < 5; i++ ) 
 
LINE 2 onclick = (function(){return function evt2() {
document.getElementById( d+i).value = event.clientX + ',' + (event.clientY-30)
};})(i);

Answer (score 0):

Ahm well I've got the first part down!

now it cycles between the 5 boxes, I'll program now an undo button which I have no idea how to do... if I make it then I'll update

I just changed the lines after:

var d = "canvas1_NewVar";

```
 var i = 1;



function evt2() {
document.getElementById( d+i).value = event.clientX + ',' + (event.clientY-30)
;
i += 1;

};
```

I created a button that reloads the page... it would be awesome to have something to go back one step but I need to remove the point in the canvas, erase the value on the box and go back 1 possition on the "i" value... that seems way to hard O_o

```
<input type="button" value="Corregir puntos" onClick="window.location.reload()">
```